# Java: Find .txt files in specified folder

Tags: java, file

Is there a built in Java code that will parse a given folder and search it for `.txt` files?

Comment: Could be answer be platform specific?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794381/how-to-find-files-that-match-a-wildcard-string-in-java

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can use the `listFiles()` method provided by the `java.io.File` class.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

public class Filter {

    public File[] finder( String dirName){
        File dir = new File(dirName);

        return dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() { 
                 public boolean accept(File dir, String filename)
                      { return filename.endsWith(".txt"); }
        } );

    }

}
```

Comment: @Funsuk, this works for me just fine, at least for the simple test cases I've tried. 36 people seem to agree. In what way does it not work for you?

Answer (score 26):

Try:

```
List<String> textFiles(String directory) {
  List<String> textFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
  File dir = new File(directory);
  for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
    if (file.getName().endsWith((".txt"))) {
      textFiles.add(file.getName());
    }
  }
  return textFiles;
}
```

You want to do a case insensitive search in which case:

```
    if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith((".txt"))) {
```

If you want to recursively search for through a directory tree for text files, you should be able to adapt the above as either a recursive function or an iterative function using a stack.

Comment: Looks good. Let me try this..

Answer (score 23):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.WildcardFileFilter;

.........
.........

File dir = new File(fileDir);
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*.txt");
File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
```

The code above works great for me

Answer (score 6):

It's really useful, I used it with a slight change:

```
filename=directory.list(new FilenameFilter() { 
    public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) { 
        return filename.startsWith(ipro); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I made my solution based on the posts I found here with Google. And I thought there is no harm to post mine as well even if it is an old thread.

The only plus this code gives is that it can iterate through sub-directories as well.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.DirectoryFileFilter;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.WildcardFileFilter;
```

Method is as follows:

```
List <File> exploreThis(String dirPath){

    File topDir = new File(dirPath);

    List<File> directories = new ArrayList<>();
    directories.add(topDir);

    List<File> textFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    List<String> filterWildcards = new ArrayList<>();
    filterWildcards.add("*.txt");
    filterWildcards.add("*.doc");

    FileFilter typeFilter = new WildcardFileFilter(filterWildcards);

    while (directories.isEmpty() == false)
    {
        List<File> subDirectories = new ArrayList();

        for(File f : directories)
        {
            subDirectories.addAll(Arrays.asList(f.listFiles((FileFilter)DirectoryFileFilter.INSTANCE)));
            textFiles.addAll(Arrays.asList(f.listFiles(typeFilter)));
        }

        directories.clear();
        directories.addAll(subDirectories);
    }

    return textFiles;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.PathMatcher;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FileFinder extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {
    private PathMatcher matcher;
    public ArrayList<Path> foundPaths = new ArrayList<>();

    public FileFinder(String pattern) {
        matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern);
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        Path name = file.getFileName();

        if (matcher.matches(name)) {
            foundPaths.add(file);
        }

        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
}

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.LinkOption;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path fileDir = Paths.get("files");
        FileFinder finder = new FileFinder("*.txt");
        Files.walkFileTree(fileDir, finder);

        ArrayList<Path> foundFiles = finder.foundPaths;

        if (foundFiles.size() > 0) {
            for (Path path : foundFiles) {
                System.out.println(path.toRealPath(LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No files were founds!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;   

List<File> htmFileList = new ArrayList<File>();

for (File file : (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(new File(srcDir), new String[]{"txt", "TXT"}, true)) {
    htmFileList.add(file);
}
```

This is my latest code to add all text files from a directory

Answer (score -2):

Here is my platform specific code(unix)

```
public static List<File> findFiles(String dir, String... names)
    {
        LinkedList<String> command = new LinkedList<String>();
        command.add("/usr/bin/find");
        command.add(dir);
        List<File> result = new LinkedList<File>();
        if (names.length > 1)
            {
                List<String> newNames = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(names));
                String first = newNames.remove(0);
                command.add("-name");
                command.add(first);
                for (String newName : newNames)
                    {
                        command.add("-or");
                        command.add("-name");
                        command.add(newName);
                    }
            }
        else if (names.length > 0)
            {
                command.add("-name");
                command.add(names[0]);
            }
        try
            {
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
                Process p = pb.start();
                p.waitFor();
                InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        // System.err.println(line);
                        result.add(new File(line));
                    }
                p.destroy();
            }
        catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Why would anyone want to use this when there is a much easier, cross-platform solution available?

Comment: One reason to use a native version is to avoid reading a huge list of files in a long directory.  In Java 6, class `java.io.File` does not include methods that read the files in a directory as a stream or using an iterator.  The Java 6 implementations of `File.listFiles(FileFilter)` and `File.listFiles(FilenameFilter)` both first read all files from a directory and then apply the filter.  When encountering a directory containing millions of files, for example, `File.listFiles` may read so many files that it may consume all of the heap memory in the JVM.

Comment: See http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/21487ef30163/src/share/classes/java/io/File.java for the implementation of `File.listFiles(FileFilter)`.