# can the scanner class be used to read the names of all of the .txt files in a specific folder?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

the title is pretty self explanatory. I need to be able to read the file names of all the .txt files in a specific folder and add them to an array. can this be done with the scanner class?

Answer (score 1):

No. A `Scanner` reads data from files, streams, Strings or anything that implements the `Readable` interface. This has nothing to do with accessing the filesystem structure. You need:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html

Comment: +1 also, strings are a possible source for scanner (:

Comment: @DorinDuminica - fair point, I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

no, you can't use scanner for that, scanner only helps you parse a string or a file's content, for what you want to achieve, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384947/java-find-txt-files-in-specified-folder)

Also, have a look at Scanner's [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, the `Scanner` class is only used for reading data in file, not read files in a folder. To read the data from a file you have specify the name file in constructor of `Scanner` while creating the object.