# Does getRuntime.exec() in java understands * or not?

Tags: java, unix

I want a list of `.tar.gz` files from a specified directory. For this I am running "`ls directory_path/*.tar.gz`" using `getRuntime.exec()` in Java. But it is not giving any output rather it is saying  `No such file or directory`..
But the same command is running on command prompt..
I am running java in unix.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `exec` won't launch a shell just to run your program. It just starts a process. On  Unix-like systems the shell is responsible for expanding wildcards to lists of files. So you would need to run `ls` through a shell to get the desired behaviour.

However, why do you use `ls` at all? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1385015/73070) shows how to get a list of files with Java.

Comment: ok thanks.can you plz explain in some more detail and how to execute ls directorypath/*.tar.gz?

Comment: ok. I want to run many unix commands using java. How to run unix commands using java?

Comment: Just run them like you would run any other program? You already did so with `ls`, you know?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You will be able to fire processes using the `exec()` not the command promt..

**2.** Better use `list()` to get the names of all the files in a directory, and then use `FileFilter` to get the .tar.gz files.