# Getting rid of file extensions?

Tags: java, servlets

help to make such a thing (in the previous answer, I was told that I was poorly explained, and now try to explain poponyatneee) I have a form, just a form, the code it is:

```
<form action="searchf" method="Post">
<input type="text" name="text" autofocus >
<input type="submit" value="">
</form>
```

The user enters into this form different file names, such as: index.txt, hello.html (files with duplicate names not, and basically it will txt files). Next, the servlet takes string that the user enters:

```
String myName = request.getParameter("text");
```

Continue program called input files looking for the files in the folder, but the fact is that it is necessary to enter index.html program to find the file in the folder, not just index, here's help to enter the extension was not necessarily trying to do so :

```
String myNamee = request.getParameter("text");
String myName = myNamee.replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "");
```

It did not work (I will be glad to any replies

*Eric Scot*

Comment: I wrote that the program looks for the entered data in a specific directory

Comment: Side note: naming variables as `myNamee` and `myName` is a bad idea, very easy to use the wrong variable with a typo. Try `inputFileWithExt` and `inputFile`, for example.

Comment: Are you expecting the user to give the filename with the extension?

Comment: I'm still new to java, could you write the code please, of what you suggested)

Comment: there he wrote the name of the file with

Comment: Ok. So if the user *has* supplied the extension, then I don't think you have a problem. You can just search for files with that name. Java considers the extension to be part of the name (e.g. `foo.txt` is the full filename).

Comment: but I need to be without. txt

Comment: When files can I print them immediately without the extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to separate the file extension from the filename, you can do something like this:

```
String file = request.getParameter("text");
String fileNoExt, fileExt = "";
if(file.indexOf(".") == -1) {
   fileNoExt = file;
else {
   fileNoExt = file.substring(0,file.lastIndexOf("."));
   fileExt  = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
}
```

I recommend that you test this code outside the context of Servlets. Just create a simple Java program with a main method to search a directory for a file and you can forget the user-input and form info. Just hard code some test data to make sure you know how to look through a directory and your code to handle the filenames is working correctly.

You may find this [other stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384947/java-find-txt-files-in-specified-folder) helpful for understanding how to serach through a directory for a file.

Comment: @EricScot - explain yourself.  In what sense did it not work?  What were the symptoms?  What were the errors?

Comment: I tried to enter and hello.txt and hello, in both cases, I was given a white screen, so there is an error (

Comment: So what did the logfile say?

Comment: @EricScot - And did you test it outside of a servlet like Thorn suggested?

Comment: nothing  14.11.2012 17:07:36 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
14.11.2012 17:07:36 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
14.11.2012 17:13:52 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

Comment: See, I realized what the problem is I have done it so it is necessary to output files from a directory without an extension and only then compare them with what the user entered)

Comment: If you tested the file access code outside of a Servlet and it worked, then there is a problem with how you are looking for files in the Servlet. Post your Servlet code or just your doGet method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not cut out everything from the last dot in the name to the end:

```
final String baseName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Comment: Thank you'll try, you will not go away)

Comment: 'String myName = request.getParameter("text");final String baseName = myName.substring(0, myName.lastIndexOf("."));'

Comment: Your version gave me this error

Comment: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1937)
 searchf.doPost(searchf.java:26)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

Comment: So work on it. If there is no dot to begin with, this is the way it fails.

Comment: just the name of my string - myName, please can do with it)