# How to convert every CSV in a folder to an XML file in Java?

Tags: java, xml, csv, directory

I'm pretty new to CSV and XML files in general, and I want to convert every CSV file in my folder to an XML file. I'd like some tips how to work with CSV files, how to go about processing and converting the files, and how to go about repeating the conversion process for every file in my folder. Thanks in advance.

Example CSV

```
id,name,surname,street,number,town
112345,gentoo,king,bourkley,6,novi sad
446636,mark,smith,milson,14,capetown
```

Example XML

```
<root>
  <entry id='1'>
    <id>112345</id>
    <name>gentoo</name>
    <surname>king</surname>
    <street>bourkley</street>
    <number>6</number>
    <town>novi sad</town>
  </entry>
  <entry id='2'>
    <id>112345</id>
    <name>mark</name>
    <surname>smith</surname>
    <street>milson</street>
    <number>14</number>
    <town>capetown</town>
  </entry>
</root>
```

Of course, I'd like the simplest possible solution. Using libraries as basic as they get.

Comment: How is the XML structued?

Comment: For a case like this, you should show some code. "What have you tried?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV Parsing: [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)

Creating an XML file: [Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/)

Finding all files of a specific type in a directory: [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1385015/1154145)

Put these together and VOILA!

Comment: Thanks for all three links! It's very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest pulling in a csv parser, like opencsv to read the csv file into a bean.  Then use a library like jaxb to serialize the bean to XML.

Instructions for parsing CSV with opencsv: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#how-to-read

Tutorial for jaxb: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Comment: Thanks for another good idea! I'll try both your idea and nattyddubbs'.

Comment: You could mix-and-match the parts of these answers that you like since they are all independent libs.

Comment: That's what I'm gonna do! Thanks for the input again! This site is really friendly towards starters!