# Filtering only .txt files

Tags: java, android

I need help modifying this so that it only reads .txt files

```
String[] savedFiles = getApplicationContext().fileList();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, savedFiles);
    listSavedFiles.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384947/java-find-txt-files-in-specified-folder

Comment: `fileList` of `Context` doesn't have an overloaded  version of `fileList` that takes a `FilenameFilter` as parameter