# How do I use directory globbing in JDK7

Tags: java, java-7, glob, java.nio.file

I have been trying to use the new globbing feature in JDK7, starting from [the documentation and examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html)

I can get globs such as `"glob:*.dat"` to work with the

```
Files.walkFileTree(startingDir, finder);
```

example but I have been unable to get the `"**"` syntax working. I would like to be able to create something like:

```
matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:" + "foo/**/bar/*.dat");
```

and would be grateful for a simple example. I am using Windows 7.

UPDATE:
@Oleg and @JBNizet make it clear that the "/" syntax is OS-independent. Note that the [Javadocs](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher%28java.lang.String%29) suggest that OS-dependent syntax is also possible (?required)

STILL PROBLEMS:
Have taken @Nizet and edited as follows:

```
@Test
public void testStackoverflowGlobber() throws IOException {
    final PathMatcher matcher =
 FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:*.cml");
        Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get("d:/petermr-workspace/jumbo-converters/jumbo-converters-cli/src/test/resources"), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                System.out.println("try>> "+file);
                if (matcher.matches(file)) {
                    System.out.println("MATCHES>>"+file);
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
}
```

and this gives output such  as:

```
try>> d:\petermr-workspace\jumbo-converters\jumbo-converters-cli\src\test\resources\examples\cdx\r19.cdx
try>> d:\petermr-workspace\jumbo-converters\jumbo-converters-cli\src\test\resources\examples\cdx\r19.cdxml
try>> d:\petermr-workspace\jumbo-converters\jumbo-converters-cli\src\test\resources\examples\cdx\r19.cml
try>> d:\petermr-workspace\jumbo-converters\jumbo-converters-cli\src\test\resources\examples\cdx\r19.ref.cdxml
try>> d:\petermr-workspace\jumbo-converters\jumbo-converters-cli\src\test\resources\examples\cdx\r19.ref.cml
try>> d:\petermr-workspace\jumbo-converters\jumbo-converters-cli\src\test\resources\examples\cif\aa2004.cml
```

but no evidence of matching

Comment: `/` will work fine on any Windows system if that's your concern

Comment: @Oleg thanks. So I have got some logic wrong or assumed the methods have different functionality. is File.separator therefore wrong? [I find the official documentation rather sketchy]

Comment: have you tried "glob:**/*.cml"?

Comment: @Kristof thanks - it seems that you have to use the `**` component

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a working example which displays all the zip files in any descendant directory of `d:/`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:d:/**/*.zip");
    Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get("d:/"), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            if (matcher.matches(file)) {
                System.out.println(file);
            }
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
}
```

As you see, using forward slashes works on Windows.

Comment: Thanks. Will it check relative file paths?

Comment: have accepted this as it's the only answer and it tackled the problem of file separator. But I can't get it to work on my environment. The globbing syntax seems rather lightly documented and there aren't clear examples. Oh well, will probably work tomorrow...

Comment: If you even want to remove the drive specific  use following `glob:*/**/*.zip`

Comment: the drive specific part can be removed with pattern `glob:**/*.zip` even the extension `glob:**/*.*`

Comment: Ummm.... this works, but it's not efficient. If your pattern is `glob:/foo/bar/baz/**/*.zip` then it will walk the entire file tree, not just the `/foo/bar/baz` component.

Answer (score 7):

You need to start your glob with **

```
matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:**/foo/**/bar/*.dat");
```

Otherwise, calling

```
matcher.matches(file)
```

attempts to match the full path to the file against a regular expression that starts with the relative path (/foo/), rather than with the absolute path (d:/petermr-workspace/.../foo).

Prepending the ** to the glob just tells it to ignore the beginning of the absolute path.