# It is possible to NOT add the typed wildcards in JFileChooser's file type combobox?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I need a JFileChooser which acts like `notepad.exe` or `mspaint.exe` in save mode. As you may know when you type wildcard (* or ?) characters in the *File name* field the file view will show only those files which are matching for the users input. This is OK, but my problem is with the *Files of type* combobox:

In `JFileChooser`: the *Files of type* combo box is updated as well when the user enters a wildcard in the *File name* field. 
See the screenshot [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45132409/in%20jfilechooser.PNG)!

But if you try this with `notepad.exe` you will realize that the *File name* field remains as it was before, so the search pattern is not updated.
See the notepad's screenshot [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45132409/in%20notepad.PNG)!

So my question is: **Does anybody know a solution how to achieve that the *Files of type* combo box should NOT be updated by the entered filter?**

I need a cross-platform solution, so it should work both on XP and Linux.

Thanks in advance!

Sorry for the links, but I am not allowed to attach it directly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution:
Using a custom file chooser UI derived from `BasicFileChooserUI` will solve my issue in the following way: I've overriden the `getApproveSelectionAction()` method with my custom action:

```
protected class CustomApproveSelectionAction extends BasicFileChooserUI.ApproveSelectionAction {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String filename = getFileName();
        // using a custom pattern to accept valid charachters only:
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(filename);

        if (matcher.matches()) { 
            // this is the good case, just let the super implementation do what have to do.
            super.actionPerformed(e);
        } else {
            // this is the bad case, we must warn the user and don't let the super implementation take effect.
            // display an error message similar like notepad does it.
        }
    }
}
```

If the filename is ok, then I allow what super implementation does, otherwise I will display a message.

Answer (score 1):

The [glob pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) recognition feature is implemented in the `FileChooserUI` delegate for each Look & Feel. For example, [`MetalFileChooserUI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/metal/MetalFileChooserUI.html) contains a nested `ApproveSelectionAction`, inherited from `BasicFileChooserUI`, that invokes `setFileFilter()`. This adds the new pattern, via a `PropertyChangeEvent`, to the listening [`MetalFileChooserUI.FilterComboBoxModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/metal/MetalFileChooserUI.FilterComboBoxModel.html). You may be able to intercept the added filter somewhere along the chain.

You may also be able to leverage the [file pattern matching](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html) capability introduced in Java 7 and discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9148528/230513).

Comment: This related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378798) can be used to examine the sequence of events described above.