# Scala - Count number of files in directory with defined file extension

Tags: file, scala

Hi I have a script which batch converts pdfs into a series of images, what I'd like to do is count the total number of files in the directory that have the extension .jpg.

So far I have

```
for (file <- new File(path).listFiles) {

     /* DO SOMETHING */

}
```

Is there a compact way of doing this without looping through each file?

Thanks in advance, much appreciated :)

Comment: In java you can do this http://stackoverflow.com/a/805504/785966

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
Option(new File(path).list).map(_.filter(_.endsWith(".jpg")).size).getOrElse(0)
```

`Option(...)` acts as a `null` check and is needed because `list` and `listFiles` may return `null`.

Comment: Learned something new. Thanks. I'd personally break it into 2-3 lines though.  I think One-liners are usually harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (file <- new java.io.File (".").listFiles;
  if (file.getName ().matches (".*\\.scala"))) println (file)
```

results in:

```
./TopTen.scala
./QuadTree.scala
./Euler093.scala
./ParallelFactorial.scala
./GenericCartesian.scala
```