# Add index to filename for existing file (file.txt => file_1.txt)

Tags: java, design-patterns, filenames

I want to add an index to a filename if the file already exists, so that I don't overwrite it.

Like if I have a file `myfile.txt` and same time `myfile.txt` exists in destination folder - I need to copy my file with name `myfile_1.txt`

And same time if I have a file `myfile.txt`, but destintation folder contains `myfile.txt` and `myfile_1.txt` - generated filename has to be `myfile_2.txt`

So the functionality is very similar to the creation of folders in Microsoft operating systems.

What's the best approach to do that?

Comment: The best approaching is writing code that does this... Then if somethnig doesn't work as expected, posting a question... BTW How many files are there to check? (I mean in range of millions, or tens?)

Comment: Take a look at [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html). UI could create loop that checks to see if each index exist or simple list the files that match the file name, sort it and grab the last index (or simply the count)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Untested Code:

```
File f = new File(filename);
String extension = "";
int g = 0;
int i = f.lastIndexOf('.');
extension = fileName.substring(i+1);

while(f.exists()) {      
  if (i > 0) 
  {  f.renameTo(f.getPath() + "\" + (f.getName() + g) + "." + extension); }
  else
  {  f.renameTo(f.getPath() + "\" + (f.getName() + g)); }     

  g++;    
}
```

Comment: filenames don't necessarily have to include an extension. MyFile is a perfectly reasonable filename.

Comment: Sorry, but this is pretty broken. As @dendini already said, files without extension are perfectly reasonable, furthermore you are going to get stuck in the loop because g is never incremented, such that f will always exists. And renameTo renames the file, and doesn't just change the string.

Answer (score 3):

Using [commons-io](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/):

```
private static File getUniqueFilename( File file )
{
    String baseName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName( file.getName() );
    String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension( file.getName() );
    int counter = 1
    while(file.exists())
    {
        file = new File( file.getParent(), baseName + "-" + (counter++) + "." + extension );
    }
    return file
}
```

This will check if for instance `file.txt` exist and will return `file-1.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You might also benefit from using the apache commons-io library. It has some usefull file manipulation methods in class FileUtils and FilenameUtils.

Answer (score -1):

Try this link partly answers your query.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/805504/1961652

```
    DirectoryScanner scanner = new DirectoryScanner();
    scanner.setIncludes(new String[]{"**/myfile*.txt"});
    scanner.setBasedir("C:/Temp");
    scanner.setCaseSensitive(false);
    scanner.scan();
    String[] files = scanner.getIncludedFiles();
```

once you have got the correct set of files, append a proper suffix to create a new file.