# How to get to a file by passing relative path in java?

Tags: java, regex, file, relative-path

I am trying to understand "How to get to file by passing relative path of a file or folder?" . Here is the example:

CODE:

```
  public class somex {
    public static void main {
       String fileName = System.getProperty("user.dir");   <---This gives me path for the current working directory.
       File file = new File(fileName + "../../xml_tutorial/sample.xlsx" );
       System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());         <---This gives me path for the file that is residing in folder called "xml_tutorial".
     }
  }

    >>>>
```

Here, I know the file location so i was able to pass correct relative path. And, managed to   print the file path. I have deleted the "sample.xlsx" and executed the above code; With no failing   it gives me the path name and it is same path as when the file exists (i.e. before deleting). How it is possible ? I am expecting EXCEPTION here. why it is not throwing exception ?

Two, I want to use regular expression for the file name, such as: "../../xml_tutorial/samp.*". But this doesn't do the job and it gives me IOException. Why it is not able to identify the file sample.xlsx ? (NOTE: this is when the file exist and one hundred precent sure there is only one file with the name "sample.xlsx")

Comment: 1. you can check the file with file.exists() method. 2. java not support wildcard, you can find answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794381/how-to-find-files-that-match-a-wildcard-string-in-java

Comment: Please ask **one** question per question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have deleted the "sample.xlsx" and executed the above code; With no failing it gives me the path name and it is same path as when the file exists (i.e. before deleting). How it is possible ? I am expecting EXCEPTION here. why it is not throwing exception ?

`File` doesn't care whether the file actually exists. It just resolves the *path*. There's no need for the file to exist in order to take the path

```
/home/tjc/a/b/c/../../file.txt
```

...and turn it into the canonical form

```
/home/tjc/a/file.txt
```

If you want to know whether the file on that path actually exists, you can use the [`exists()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29).

---

On your second, unrelated question:

> Two, I want to use regular expression for the file name, such as: "../../xml_tutorial/samp.*". But this doesn't do the job and it gives me IOException. Why it is not able to identify the file sample.xlsx ?

There's nothing in the [`File` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) saying that it supports wildcards. If you want to do searches, you'll want to use [`list(FilenameFilter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29) or [`listFiles(FilenameFilter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29) and a [`FilenameFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) implementation, or [`listFiles(FileFilter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29) and a [`FileFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) implementation.