# Using wildcard when listing files in directory with java

Tags: java

Why does a wildcard not work in java code below?
My request looks like `http://localhost:8080/App/DataAccess?location=Dublin`

```
rob@work:~$ ls /usr/local/CustomAppResults/Dublin/*/.history
/usr/local/CustomAppResults/Dublin/team1/.history
/usr/local/CustomAppResults/Dublin/team2/.history
/usr/local/CustomAppResults/Dublin/team3/.history
```

Servlet code (DataAccess.java).
`(DataAccess.java:27)` refers to the for loop ..

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        File[] files = finder("/usr/local/CustomAppResults/" + 
                            request.getParameter("location") + "/*/");

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){

                    System.out.println(files[i].getName());
        }
    }

    private File[] finder(String dirName) {

        File dir = new File(dirName);

        return dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                return filename.endsWith(".history");
            }
        });
    }
```

Error:

```
The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
from fulfilling this request.
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.example.servlets.DataAccess.doGet(DataAccess.java:27)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find files that match a wildcard string in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794381/how-to-find-files-that-match-a-wildcard-string-in-java)

Comment: The [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html) covers glob matching in java.nio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `public File[] listFiles(FilenameFilter filter)`

> Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

So, why do you get this situation? You are trying to use a wildcard char (`*`) that is evaluated by your shell, but won't be evaluated in `new File(path)`. The `new File(path)` constructor only works for exact paths.

Things like `DirectoryScanner` (Apache Ant) or `FileUtils` (Apache commons-io) will solve your problem. See the comments above for further details on possible solutions, including the Java 7 NIO approach (`Files.newDirectoryStream( path, glob-pattern )`).

Comment: used `DirectoryScanner` (Apache Ant), worked a treat .. thanks