# Get content of a file inside a directory

Tags: java, file-io, java-8

I want to get the content of a file inside a directory:

```
/sys/block/sda/device/model
```

I use this code to get the content:

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/sys/block/sda/device/model")));
```

But in some scenarios, I have cases like this:

```
/sys/block/sda/device/model
/sys/block/sdb/device/model
/sys/block/sdc/device/model
```

How I can iterate all the directories starting with

`sd*` and print the file `model`?

Can you show me some example for Java 8 with filter?

Comment: I think there is backward links in the directory that you reading from. its just a hypothesis. can you check that?

Comment: check on filters http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_listfiles_file_filter.htm

Comment: Can you check if this post helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794381/how-to-find-files-that-match-a-wildcard-string-in-java

Comment: Can you show me some working example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do this using Java 8 features:

```
Function<Path,byte[]> uncheckedRead = p -> {
  try { return Files.readAllBytes(p); }
  catch(IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
};
try(Stream<Path> s=Files.find(Paths.get("/sys/block"), 1,
    (p,a)->p.getName(p.getNameCount()-1).toString().startsWith("sd"))) {
  s.map(p->p.resolve("device/model")).map(uncheckedRead).map(String::new)
   .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

This is an example that strives for compactness and working stand-alone. For real applications, it’s likely that you would do it a bit differently. The task of using an IO operation as a `Function` which doesn’t allow checked exception is quite common so you might have a wrapper function like:

```
interface IOFunction<T,R> {
    R apply(T in) throws IOException;
}
static <T,R> Function<T,R> wrap(IOFunction<T,R> f) {
    return t-> { try { return f.apply(t); }
      catch(IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
    };
}
```

Then you can use

```
try(Stream<Path> s=Files.find(Paths.get("/sys/block"), 1,
    (p,a)->p.getName(p.getNameCount()-1).toString().startsWith("sd"))) {
  s.map(p->p.resolve("device/model")).map(wrap(Files::readAllBytes))
   .map(String::new).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

But maybe you’d use `newDirectoryStream` instead even if the returned `DirectoryStream` is not a `Stream` and hence requires a manual `Stream` creation as this method allows passing a glob pattern like `"sd*"`:

```
try(DirectoryStream<Path> ds
                     =Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/sys/block"), "sd*")) {
  StreamSupport.stream(ds.spliterator(), false)
    .map(p->p.resolve("device/model")).map(wrap(Files::readAllBytes))
    .map(String::new).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Finally, the option to process the files as stream of lines should be mentioned:

```
try(DirectoryStream<Path> ds
                     =Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/sys/block"), "sd*")) {
  StreamSupport.stream(ds.spliterator(), false)
    .map(p->p.resolve("device/model")).flatMap(wrap(Files::lines))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather using `st*` it's better if you can first search the existing folder inside the path `/sys/block` by using below code.

Please find working example :-

```
String dirNames[] = new File("E://block").list();
for(String name : dirNames)
{
    if (new File("E://block//" + name).isDirectory())
    {
        if(name.contains("sd")){
            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("E://block//"+name+"//device//model")));
            System.out.println(content);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @PeterPenzov I have edited my answer to provide the full solution, I tested in my system and its working fine.

Comment: By the way is this for Java 8? Is there other more optimized for performance way?

Comment: @Peter Penzov: no, besides your own `readAllBytes` part this code is not the slightest Java 8 related. Id doesn’t even uses Java 7 features.

Comment: Can you please show me how this code can be implemented with the new Java 8 features?