# Get filename from sdcard which first name is"A"

Tags: java

Get filename from sdcard which first name is "A" in java.

There are five pictures in my sdcard. Files name: A1.jpg A2.jpg A3.jpg B2.jpg C3.jpg

How can I get filename (A1.jpg A2.jpg A3.jpg) in java?

Comment: Is this mobile framework related question? Can you please show us programming context about which you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a wildcard like this: [How to find files that match a wildcard string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794381/how-to-find-files-that-match-a-wildcard-string-in-java)

or you read all Files [Read all files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844688/read-all-files-in-a-folder) and filter them in Memory.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can use `.startsWith` and use `.getName()` with `File` class (or `.getFileName()` with `Path` class)

Example

```
if (file.getName().startsWith("A")) {
 // ..
}
```