# How to open a file without knowing its extension but knowing full name?

Tags: android, android-intent

```
 Intent tostart = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                tostart.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(video_path+".***"), "video/*");
                startActivity(tostart);
```

Let's say I have a file path

```
/mnt/sdcard/video/my_birthday_moovie001
```

'my_birthday_moovie001' can be either `.mkv`, `.mpg` or `.mkv`. I've tried to add ".***" to the file path but I still can't open the file.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/805504/1320616

Comment: I really don't want to scan for files because I have alot of them in directory and I already have file path without extension in my database (don't ask why, I know it was a bad idea)

Comment: You could compare if the path matches with any filename(it doesn't contains the extension) and then if it does you got it.

Comment: @Skizo that sound like an answer, if there is no other more beautiful methods

Comment: Maybe try it to open with your predefined extensions in a loop? And catch the exceptions. Where no exception was thrown, you found your extension.

Comment: go to the directory, get all the files. Now compare the name.

Comment: Added an answer @artouiros ;)

Comment: @artouiros sorry for late reply but u may this in this way for ur exact answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i read the comments you have stored your path in db without extensions there are many extensions that exists so android cant automatically pick the extension you have to create some way to detect extension.

following is a robust way that is best match in your case but not recommended in proper cases where extensions are known

```
public String chk_path(String filePath)
{
//create array of extensions
String[] ext=new String[]{".mkv",".mpg"}; //You can add more as you require

//Iterate through array and check your path which extension with your path exists

String path=null;
for(int i=0;i<ext.Length;i++)
{
  File file = new File(filePath+ext[i]);
  if(file.exists())
    { 
     //if it exists then combine the extension
     path=filePath+ext[i];
     break;
    }
}
return path; 
}
```

now to play a song in your code

```
if(chk_path(video_path)!=null)
{
 Intent tostart = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                tostart.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(video_path), "video/*");
                startActivity(tostart);
}
else
 //tell user that although the path in database but file on this path do not exists
```

Answer (score 1):

Well as I put on comments

> You could compare if the path matches with any filename(it doesn't contains the extension) and then if it does you got it.

You can simply do this :

**Get the directory path**

```
File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

**Set the file name `my_birthday_moovie001` on my example I put `unnamed` but change it as your like**

```
String NameOfFile = "unnamed";
```

**Add the `videos`, I put it `Downloads` but you can change it**

```
String PathWithFolder = extStore + "/Download/";
```

**Create a method that lists all the files from your path**

```
private List<String> getListFiles(File parentDir) {
    ArrayList<String> inFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    File[] files = parentDir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            inFiles.addAll(getListFiles(file));
        } else {
            String AbsolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            //Get the file name ex : unnamed.jpg
            String nameofFile = AbsolutePath.substring(AbsolutePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, AbsolutePath.length());
            //Remove the .jpg --> Output unnamed
            String fileNameWithoutExtension = nameofFile.substring(0, nameofFile.lastIndexOf('.'));
            //Add each file
            inFiles.add(fileNameWithoutExtension);
        }
    }
    return inFiles;
}
```

**You got the names of the files doing this**

```
List<String> files = getListFiles(new File(PathWithFolder));
```

**Simply add a `for` that looks for a match of your `file`**

```
for (int i = 0; i<=files.size()-1; i++){
   if(PathWithFolder.equals(files.get(i))) {
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You got it!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
   else{
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You don't.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

If you want to get the path as well and do what `@Zain Ul Abidin` proposed  and compare it on `getListFiles()` method add this :

```
String fileExtension = nameofFile.substring(nameofFile.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this method, but I found that @Zain Ul Abidin answer would be faster.(because my files.size() will return a number with 3 zeros) Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the other question :

Consider DirectoryScanner from Apache Ant:

```
DirectoryScanner scanner = new DirectoryScanner();
scanner.setIncludes(new String[]{"**/*.java"});
scanner.setBasedir("C:/Temp");
scanner.setCaseSensitive(false);
scanner.scan();
String[] files = scanner.getIncludedFiles();
```

You'll need to reference ant.jar (~ 1.3 MB for ant 1.7.1).

And then, run on files array and check
 if files[i].include(yourfile)
 yourfile= files[i]

Answer (score 0):

You may try in this way , first getting the name of file and extension then finally compare and implement. like this :

Example file name is 04chamelon and extension is .png:

```
File f = new File("/mnt/storage/sdcard/Pictures/04chameleon");
        File yourDir = new File("/mnt/storage/sdcard/Pictures");
        nametwo = f.getName();
        for (File fa : yourDir.listFiles()) {
            if (fa.isFile())
                fa.getName();
            String path = fa.getName(); // getting name and extension
            filextension = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".") + 1); // seperating extension
            name1 = fa.getName();
            int pos = name1.lastIndexOf(".");
            if (pos > 0) {
                name1 = name1.substring(0, pos);
            }
        }
        if (name1.equals(nametwo)) {
            Intent tostart = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            tostart.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(f + "." + filextension), "image/*");
            //tostart.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(f + "." + filextension), "video/*");
            startActivity(tostart);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the latest `ContentResolver`, you can easily make this work using the `contentResolver.getType(uri)` function which detects the filetype.

```
private fun getIntentForFile(intent: Intent, filePath: String, context: Context): Intent { 
    val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(                                                  
        context,                                                                           
        context.applicationContext.packageName + ".fileprovider",                          
        File(filePath)                                                                     
    )                                                                                      
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)                                              
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)                                 

    intent.setDataAndType(uri, context.contentResolver.getType(uri))                       
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                                        
    return intent                                                                          
}
```