# Java IO file filtering at source

Tags: java, file-io, filesystems

How to filter files at the source itself in Java? I want to know if there is any file-system level filter available which takes in a regex and returns only matching results.

I know there is `FileFilter` interface but, this does post filtering after getting all the files under a directory when passed to `listFiles()` if I'm not wrong.

Comment: `filter files at the source itself` - I dont get u

Comment: @TheCoder I mean at the OS level itself. When I call file.listFiles(filter), it should return me filtered results. Is there anything like that?

Comment: Maybe this is what youre looking for: [how-to-find-files-that-match-a-wildcard-string-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794381/how-to-find-files-that-match-a-wildcard-string-in-java)