# Open file with most similar name

Tags: java, regex, file, fileinputstream

I have a directory with files.
I have a function that takes a `String fileName`. I would like to either be able to open that file and if it does not exist open a file that has the most similar name.
E.g.
If filename passed is `file_name_v1.txt` then if that does not exist open `file_name_v2.txt`
These are just examples. I don’t really know know the actual number after `_v` so I don’t know how I could create a regex for a file for this case

Comment: Sort file names by dictionary order

Comment: You mean all files in the dir?

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered here: [How to find files that match a wildcard string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794381/how-to-find-files-that-match-a-wildcard-string-in-java/31685610#31685610)

Note that the solutions above requires Java 7 NIO.

```
PathMatcher pathMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault()
    .getPathMatcher("regex:Test.[\\/]sample\\w+\\.txt");
try (DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(
        new File("..").toPath(), pathMatcher::matches)) {
    dirStream.forEach(path -> System.out.println(path));
}
```