# How to use wildcards in filenames when reading in files

Tags: java, wildcard

I'm working on an application that will read in SystemOut.Log files and process them. Sometimes archived files may be named slightly differently, such as SystemOut_10:20_09/07/2021-10:45_09/07/2021.Log. It's always of the form SystemOut(Some more text here).Log.

I had a little read up and stumbled across wildcards and came to the conclusion that if I were to pass SystemOut*.Log into my application as the filename it would work. But I was wrong.

I originally get my filename through a properties file like so.

```
fileName=prop.getProperty("fileName");
```

I then just tried to concatenate `*.Log` on the end.

```
fileName=fileName+"*.Log";
```

When I print out `fileName` it is "SystemOut*.Log" but when I pass in this filename to my method that reads files it doesn't work as no file is found with that name.

Am I making an error in the code or have I just misunderstood how wildcards work? Thanks

Comment: It's the same question to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794381/how-to-find-files-that-match-a-wildcard-string-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) from [Apache commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) (listFiles and iterateFiles methods):
The code you need is

```
File dir = new File(".");
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*.Log");
File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(files[i]);
}
```

Comment: Ohh perfect thank you I didn't realize you had to take these extra steps. I mistakenly assumed you could just pass it into the filename. I'll install Apache now and get this sorted thank you

Comment: `*.x` is known as *globbing* and is a feature of shells and thus will only work there. The solution proposed is the sort of thing you need, but there's no need for a 3rd party api to do it.

Comment: @g00se just out of interest then how would you do it using built in API?

Comment: Strangely there are *two* classes for that in the api: `FileFilter` and `FilenameFilter`